# Remove duplicate rows using sum

Tags: sql, sum

I have this query here and I'm trying to remove the duplicate rows which have the same offer_request.id. My guess was using the sum function, but so far I haven't found a solution here. Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

```
SELECT
to_char(ofr.created, 'YYYY-MM') AS "month",
SUM(
    CASE WHEN ae. "type" LIKE 'OfferRequestStatusChanged'
    AND ae.data ->> 'oldStatus' LIKE 'New'
    AND ae.data ->> 'status' LIKE 'UserUnreachable' THEN
        1
    end)::decimal / 
SUM(
    CASE WHEN ae."type" LIKE 'OfferRequestStatusChanged'
    AND ae.data ->> 'oldStatus' LIKE 'New'
    AND ae.data ->> 'status' IN ('Validated', 'Cancelled', 'OnHold') THEN
        1
    end)::decimal AS "ratio"
FROM 
    "application_event" ae
    JOIN "offer_request" ofr ON ofr."id" = (ae.data ->> 'offerRequestId')::int
    LEFT JOIN "offer_request_industry_sectors_industry_sector" oris ON oris."offerRequestId" = 
    ofr."id"
    LEFT JOIN "industry_sector" ids ON ids."id" = oris."industrySectorId"
WHERE
    ae."type" LIKE 'OfferRequestStatusChanged'
    AND ids."key" NOT IN ('DEVICE_SERVICE', 'ESTATE_AGENT', 'MORTGAGES', 'FINANCE_CONSULTING', 
    'SEARCH_MANDATE', 'RENOVATION_COACH', 'RENT_TO_BUY_CONSULTING')
    AND ofr."status" NOT LIKE 'Deleted'
    AND ofr."userEmail" NOT LIKE '%@houzy.ch'
    AND ofr."userEmail" NOT LIKE '%@mailinator.com'
    AND ofr."created" > '2021-06-01'
GROUP BY
    to_char(ofr.created, 'YYYY-MM');
```

Comment: WHich dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.